# Custom \if command to check for multiple conditions

Tags: conditionals

I'm creating a document class for bachelors' and masters' theses at my faculty. It's almost ready and tuned to this year's official requirements. However, things may change in future: for example, the management may suddenly change the title page layout or do anything like this. So, I want to add version options to my class to be specified like in the following:

```
\documentclass[v2018]{physvsuThesis}
```

With the help of these options, I plan to retain backward compatibility while being able to incorporate new requirements on demand.

However, I don't know how to manage such conditionals in a convenient way. Using plain TeX's `\newif` along does not seem like a viable option. The only solution I can think of is to roll out my custom commands to implement conditional logic, like this:

```
\DeclareOption{v2018}{\setVersion{2018}}
\DeclareOption{v2019}{\setVersion{2019}}
...

\ifVersion{2018, 2019} % logical OR
  ...
\fi
```

How can I implement the `\ifVersion` command so it can check for multiple conditions and work even if nested?

Comment: see if some of the stuff in `etoolbox` can help. It reduced the code for my faculty letter class quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A one liner in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% this assumes that \classversion contains the version

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifVersion}{mmO{}}
 {% #1 is a list of items of the form {year,...}
  % #2 is the code to execute in case of a match
  % #3 (optional) is the code to use in case of no match
  \str_if_in:nVTF { #1 } \classversion { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn { nV } { T, F, TF }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\classversion{2018} % emulate what the class does

\begin{document}

\ifVersion{2018}{Version 2018}[Not version 2018]

\ifVersion{2017,2018}{This is 2017 or 2018}

\ifVersion{2016}{Nothing} $\leftarrow$ nothing

\ifVersion{2016}{Nothing}[Not 2016]

\ifVersion{2016,2017}{Nothing} $\leftarrow$ nothing

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation using `expl3` with `\if ... \fi`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N\g_my_version_str
\NewDocumentCommand\setVersion{ m }{
  \str_gset:Nn \g_my_version_str { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\ifVersion{ m }{
  \clist_if_in:nVTF { #1 } {\g_my_version_str} {\iftrue} {\iffalse}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\setVersion{2018}
\ifVersion{2017, 2018}
+1\\
\fi
\ifVersion{2017, 2015}
+2\\
\fi
\end{document}
```

This leads to problems in nested conditionals because TeX does not see `\ifVersion` as a `\if` command, so the `\else`/`\fi` parsing gets out of sync in an unevaluated context.

Instead it is better to pass the conditional commands as arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N\g_my_version_str
\NewDocumentCommand\setVersion{ m }{
  \str_gset:Nn \g_my_version_str { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\ifVersion{ m }{
  \clist_if_in:nVTF { #1 } {\g_my_version_str}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\setVersion{2018}
\ifVersion{2017, 2018}{+1}{Not +1}
\ifVersion{2017, 2015}{+2}{Not +2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with no package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setVersion}[1]{\def\fire@version{#1}}

\setVersion{2018-06-08}

\newcommand{\ifVersion}[1]{\ifnum\numexpr#1>0
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\newcommand\IS[1]{%
  \if0\expandafter\pdfstrcmp\expandafter{\fire@version}{#1}%
    \expandafter1%
  \else
    \expandafter0%
  \fi}

\newcommand\ISNOT[1]{%
  \if0\expandafter\pdfstrcmp\expandafter{\fire@version}{#1}%
    \expandafter0%
  \else
    \expandafter1%
  \fi}

\newcommand\AND[2]{(#1*#2)}

\newcommand\OR[2]{(#1+#2-#1*#2)}

\newcommand\NOT[1]{(1-#1)}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifVersion
{\AND{\OR{\OR{\IS{v1}}{\IS{v2}}}{\IS{2018-06-08}}}{\ISNOT{2017-05-11}}}
{YES}
{NO}
% YES

\ifVersion
{\OR{\OR{\OR{\IS{v1}}{\IS{v2}}}{\IS{2018-06-08}}}{\IS{2017-05-11}}}
{YES}
{NO}
% YES

\ifVersion
{\AND{\OR{\OR{\IS{v1}}{\IS{v2}}}{\IS{2018-06-08}}}{\IS{2017-05-11}}}
{YES}
{NO}
% NO

\end{document}
```

The above solution uses `\pdfstrcmp` because I didn't want to assume version numbers would be only numeric.

[image]

The above is nestable with no problem.

Now, for more convenient infix notations, you can use  [`xintexpr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) which provides `\xintifboolexpr` as well as the functions `bool()` and `togl()`. Check the docs. This will allow you to combine (with `bool()`) TeX conditionals in arbitrarily complicated logic expressions.

Comment: which of course fails in lualatex since it does not support `\pdfstrcmp` ... ;-)

Comment: @daleif it does under another name (functionality equivalent to `\pdfstrcmp` is requirement of LaTeX3, and as far as I know LaTeX3 is compatible with lualatex...)

Comment: Exactly, just mentioning it here for others to come, that they cannot expect the the solution works in all LaTeX engines.

Comment: it is only a matter of adding the suitable per engine definition either as a primitive or some `\directlua` or whatever from copying-pasting how LaTeX3 sets it up.

Comment: @daleif well after advanced research I could determine that xetex has `\strcmp` and that for luatex, one can try to un-LaTeX3 lines 1055 etc in l3str.dtx and also use l3kernel.strcmp from l3luatex.dtx...  (lines 447 et al)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit overkill, but can be done with iterating. Using e.g. `pgffor` and `xstring`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newif\ifIsInList

% #1: haystack
% #2: needle
% #3: action if found in list
% #4: action if not found in list
\gdef\isin#1#2#3#4{
    \global\IsInListfalse%
    \def\needle{#2}%
    \def\haystack{#1}%
    \makeatletter\IfInteger{\needle}{}{\@latex@error{ISIN: Can't look for list item that is not numeric!}{}\bye\stop}\makeatother%
    \IfInteger{\haystack}{%
        \ifnum\haystack=\needle\relax%
            #3%
        \else%
            #4%
        \fi%
    }{%
        \foreach \pp in {#1}{%
                \ifnum\pp=\needle\relax%
                    \global\IsInListtrue%
                    #3%
                \fi%
            }%
        \ifIsInList\else%
            #4%
        \fi%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
%\isin{Comma Separated List}{Look for}{If found}{If not found}
\isin{2011,2012}{2011}{2011 is in the list!}{2011 is not in the list}%
\isin{2011,2012}{2013}{2013 is in the list!}{2013 is not in the list}
\end{document}
```

`xstring` is not strictly needed - just to catch the error if the first argument is an integer, and make sure that the second argument is an integer.